# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'sName' in a bean of type 'AddUserBean'

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, javabeans

I have a html page with a user registration form. I collect the data and action is :

```
<form name="register" action="../JSP/Register.jsp" method="post">
```

Then on the jsp page i have

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Reg JSP</TITLE>

    <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="commonstyle.css">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<jsp:useBean id ="user" class ="Data.AddUserBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name ="user" property="*" />

<H1>
    Customer Name :    <jsp:getProperty name = "user" property = "sName" /><br>
    Age :<jsp:getProperty name = "user" property = "iAge" /><br>
    Email:<jsp:getProperty name = "user" property = "sEmail" /><br>

</H1>
```

The bean is in Package Data; This is a java class having get and set methods for these three properties sName, iAge and sEmail.

When I am trying to execute the code, it gives me error :

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   Cannot find any information on
>   property 'sName' in a bean of type
>   'Data.AddUserBean'

I am using Tomcat 6 and Eclipse IDE.

Any Suggestions???

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. And as always Balus C you are the life saviour !!! It was the naming Issue, in the setter method, I have used caps name by mistake. That was creating trouble. I changed it to lower case and everything started working. Thanks once again for everyone who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), this makes no sense in an OO language like Java and makes stuff unnecessarily complex in Javabeans and EL. Also get rid of capitalized characters in package names, this is disallowed as per [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

```
package data;

public class AddUserBean { 
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
}
```

and rewrite the JSP as follows (capitalized HTML elements is also *too* '90s, are you sure you're reading up-to-date tutorials/books?):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Reg JSP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="user" class="data.AddUserBean" />
        <jsp:setProperty name ="user" property="*" />
        <h1>
            Customer Name: ${user.name}<br>
            Age: ${user.age}<br>
            Email: ${user.email}<br>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, the [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) (EL, those `${}` things) provides you easy instant access to javabeans in any scope. The `jsp:getProperty` is only useful when there is no EL (nor JSTL) support, but then we're talking about the time before a decade ago. Surely the servletcontainer you're currently using supports EL.

#### See also:

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Comment: Hi, I tried everything and also renamed all the properties to lowercase. Still the same error. Id there some special setting or mapping required for Eclipse ?

Comment: If you get the same error, then you haven't changed the code accordingly or not rebuilt/redeployed the code correctly. Cleanup everything and retry.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AddUserBean` class has properties `Name`, `Age` and `Email`, then why are you asking it for  `sName`, `iAge` and `sEmail`? This is inconsistent.

Comment: Sir the property name is sName, iAge, sEmail

Comment: @Tara: OK, I see the edit. Those are very odd property names. Please post the actual source for the class, rather than just describing it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<jsp:getProperty name = "user" property = "SEmail" />
```

I would, however, advice to use simply `email`, rather than `sEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

> `org.apache.jasper.JasperException`: Cannot find any information on property `'sName'` in a bean of type `'AddUserBean'`

Is it the page cannot get my java bean file?

No, it looks more like a problem with your JSPs. Bean property names
begin with lowercase letters (unless you expend considerable effort to
make it otherwise). It is potentially confusing that the initial
lowercase letter by convention appears uppercase in getter and setter
names; for example, `getEmpName()` and `setEmpName(String)` would be the
getter and setter for property `empName`.

If Jasper couldn't find the bean class then it would have said so; if it
goes so far as to check the presence of a particular property then it
has already introspected the bean class.

Answer (score 0):

Just Name the Variables as suggested in JAVA naming Convention i.e. in Small Letter.
eg.: Private String name;

Private String Name;  -----------> will throw exception.